# How to check via aws cli if a Security Group description contains a secific string?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Using aws cli, I would like to be able to fuzzy search for a part of a string in the 'description' of a Security Group.

For example let's say Security Group **sd-afafaf00** contains "Hey there kaipee" in the Description field.

The following works but only for a complete match, not partial

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?IpPermissions[?contains(IpRanges[].Description, 'Hey there kaipee')]]"
```

I would like to be able to display all Security Groups that contain 'kaipee' in the description, like:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?IpPermissions[?contains(IpRanges[].Description, 'kaipee')]]"
```

EDIT : I require returning the GroupId, CirdIp and details of the Description field which all match the results of the queried string.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind using jq?

```
jq '.[][].IpPermissions[].IpRanges[] | select(.Description) | select(.Description | contains("kaipee"))'
```

Comment: Using jq seems fine. However for more clarity, I actually require returning the GroupId, CidrIp and Description for each value that matches the queried string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a JMESPath query to filter the SG you're looking for. I've done some testing on my own and can't find the way to get  `contains` to work, but I find that `>` seems to work even when the search string is not at the start of the description.

`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?Description > 'kaipee'].{Description: Description, GroupId: GroupId, IpRanges: IpPermissions[].IpRanges}"`

Hope that helps.